# Javascript dynamic link issues?

Tags: javascript

There might be a duplicate of this (I've tried checking questions on creating dynamic links but they reference a static link - I want this link to be hidden from the user). On testing the following code on the ww3 site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<a href=&quot;www.google.com&quot;>Google</a>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I get:

```
 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/%22www.google.com%22
```

As the link address rather than www.google.com.

How do I correct this problem? And how do I make it so the link only appears after a set time? Note, this is a simplified version of the code for readability (the dynamic link will including two floating point variables assigned at the time the script is run).

Comment: You'd need to use a full URL. What's the point of a link hidden from a user? And you're aware it's not really hidden, correct?

Comment: A link that isn't generated on the page until after a timer has expired. It won't be hidden if they can view the code, but because it uses random variables, they'd have trouble getting the actual link if you get me. See it as a sort of scripted hide and seek challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

1) You need `http://` before the URL so it's: http://www.google.com
2) You don't need to use quotes in document.write, but if you want to you can do one of these 3:

```
document.write('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
document.write("<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>");
document.write("<a href=http://www.google.com>Google</a>");
```

Comment: You can also escape a matching quotation.

Answer (score 3):

An `<a>` tag's `href` must include the protocol `http://`, otherwise it links to a document relative to the page the link is on:

```
// Print quote literals, not html entities `&quot;`
document.write("<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>");
```

The use cases for `document.write()` are often limited since it can't be used after the page has loaded without overwriting the whole thing. A lot of the time you will want to create the element after the page has already rendered. In that case, you would use `document.createElement()` and `appendChild()`.

```
// Create the node...
var newlink = document.createElement('a');
newlink.href = 'http://www.google.com';
// Set the link's text:
newlink.innerText = "Google";

// And add it to the appropriate place in the DOM
// This just sticks it onto the <body>
// You might, for example, instead select a specific <span> or <div>
// by its id with document.getElementById()
document.body.appendChild(newlink);
```

By the way, w3schools is not affiliated with the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/), and their examples are generally not recommended since they are often out of date or incomplete.

Comment: @user1433767 It probably didn't display anything because the link via `createElement` had no innerText or innerHTML (nothing between `<a></a>`)  See http://jsfiddle.net/y2Gz6/ . It is very simple and will work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the slash "\" to escape the quote

Answer (score 0):

To make the link absolute, include the "http://" at the start of the url. Write out:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
```

instead of

```
<a href="www.google.com">
```

The second example will be treated as a relative url, like `index.html` for example.